# How i get events in electron webcontents?

Tags: javascript, web, electron

I'm using electron application. Use web contents in BrowserView.

Can I get events in 
[this webcontents Events?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPN9P.png)

I just tried like this

```
view.Webcontents.on("Media-play",function(){
    console.log("blah-blah-");
})
```

But I can't get.

I want to handle events like

[image: this]

How I get this events?

Comment: Do you mean custom events or Dom events?

Comment: **I mean dom.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WebContents:**

Event Listener for Electron Webcontents:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 1500 })
win.loadURL('http://github.com');

win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
   console.log('finished to load ');
})
```

Possible WebContent events. Refer: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#instance-events

**Webview:**

Event listener for electron `webviews`.

HTML:

```
<webview id="webview" src="content.html"></webview>
```

Js:

```
let webview = document.getElementById("webview");
webview.addEventListener("dom-ready", () => {
     console.log("blah-blah-");
});
```

Possible webview dom events. Refer: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#dom-events